# Run Monad operations wrapped by another Monad

Tags: haskell, yesod

Given the [websockets example](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/e2e546df4d062e182da79a20115d1334055ee1a9/yesod-websockets/chat.hs#L22-L23) how can I have `Handler` related operations such as `runDB` inside (e.g. `runDB $ selectList ...`)

Here's a non working example of what I want to do:

```
chatStream :: WebSocketsT Handler ()
chatStream = do
    users <- liftIO $ runDB $ selectList [] [] :: Handler [Entity User] -- This line is not working
    sendTextData ("Welcome to the chat server, please enter your name." :: Text)
     -- ....
```

Here's the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘HandlerT App IO [Entity User]’
               with ‘ReaderT
                       websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Connection.Connection
                       Handler
                       t0’
Expected type: ReaderT
                 websockets-0.9.7.0:Network.WebSockets.Connection.Connection
                 Handler
                 t0
  Actual type: Handler [Entity User]
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  users <- liftIO $ runDB $ selectList [] [] :: Handler [Entity User]
```

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting to the question please

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've added the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `lift` and not `liftIO`

`users <- lift $ (runDB $ selectList [] [] :: Handler [Entity User])`